# Download image on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, fastapi

i have a simple function in fastapi python

```
url="some_random_video_url_here"
re = requests.get(url)
with open("download/hello.png", 'wb') as file: #save hello.png to download folder
    file.write(re.content)
    file.close()
```

this function work locally fine and download image and any files bot when upload on heroku not download image and save in staticsFiles folder

please help

Comment: first you should check if you get any error message in logs. Second you should check in documentation if heroku doesn't block access to external servers - to stop spamers/hackers/bots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral/short lived. This means that any images you save locally will disappear after you redeploy your app. You can't rely on Heroku's filesystem to store images that need to persist for a longer time.

For saving images, have a look at 3rd party storage solutions such as Cloudinary or AWS S3.